# How to get updated field without calling the model again in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, slim

I just want to know is there a way to get updated record without calling the model again?

for example

```
$point = 5;
$user = User::find(1);
$user->increment('point', $point); //

echo $user->point; // I get 0 from this
```

but if I call the model again

```
$user = User::find(1);

return $user->point; // I get 5 from this
```

Thankyou before.

Comment: have you tried calling $user->save() after you increment?

Comment: @luminoslty isn't increment just like update method?

Comment: Yes it is - calling `save()` is redundant, and would not change anything.

Comment: @ghabriel wasn't sure, not too familiar with laravel in particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eloquent models have a [refresh](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_refresh) method:

```
$point = 5;
$user = User::find(1);
$user->increment('point', $point);

return $user->refresh()->point;
```